# Can we forecast how a windows application will work if the machine specification is changed?

Tags: windows

I am looking for a solution that will monitor an application 's memory and cpu utilization and use that profile to give me an idea of how the same process will work if the specification is changed?

Do we have an application for the same?

Comment: Startup a Virtual Machine (HyperV, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc...) with reduced memory and CPU cores.  Test your application in that environment.

Comment: You can kinda simulate a slower processor with a Power Profile from Control Panel: https://imgur.com/a/WZSEs4t

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1359632/how-can-i-simulate-a-pc-having-less-physical-memory-than-it-does-to-test-perform

Comment: All the above solutions are restricted to the machine spec in which the current solution is hosted,right ?
I wanted to know the CPU Utilization when a spec is increased when compared with the current machine where it is hosted.
Reason for this question is to check how many instances of the same application can be side loaded.